# Are extract files from openmaptiles.org subject to the same IP issues of the osm2vectortiles project?

Tags: openmaptiles

I have an older project that used the https://github.com/osm2vectortiles/osm2vectortiles project to generate vector map data in the mbtiles format. I now see the notice about possible intellectual property infringement from Mapbox, so i want to replace it. I'm considering just purchasing an extract from https://openmaptiles.org, but those files also use the mbtiles format. Is the IP issue related to just the vector data storage or the schema of the mbtiles db as well? In other words, have the files available for purchase been updated to use the new vector schema (https://openmaptiles.org/schema/). If so, I assume those files available for purchase are free of potential licensing issues from Mapbox? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Files from OpenMapTiles using same mbtiles format for storing tiles and metadata but schema in vector tiles are updated to the new vector schema without license problems.